# How can I get an android app to a client for review prior to public release?

Tags: android

I can't put my android app to app store. I need a way to send my apps to clients privately. Plz suggest me some methods to do this.Its important. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not export an APK and email it across to the client??

Comment: are you talking about android or iphone???? edit your tags

Comment: right now, i have android app. but this suggestion could help me for iphone app too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send him the apk via email or upload it to any site. Your client will need to download the apk and install it manually.